# Ajax Call returning 'undefined' - Companies House API

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting data via Companies House API and it loops fine when I output the json array out on the page, but when I come to looping it out in jQuery I get about 16 undefined results. I've tried to find an answer everywhere but I just can't seem so suss it. My only thought is that the 16 undefined are buried inside another object?

Any help would be really appreciated, code below:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('[data-button-search]').click(function(event) {
      var $this = $(this);
      event.preventDefault();
      var value = $('[data-company-id]').val();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "https://link.to.site.com/company/"+value+"/name",
          dataType: 'json', // ** ensure you add this line **
          success: function(data){
              $.each(data, function(){
                  $.each(this, function(key, val) {
                      console.log(val.title + " : company number : " + val.company_number);
                      $('[data-select]').append(`
                          <option value='`+key+`'>`+val.title+`</option>
                      `);
                  });
              });
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log("Error!");
          }
      });

  });
});
```

Sample Array which is a result of me entering "AWD" into the search box:

```
{
  "items_per_page": 50,
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "AWD  LTD",
      "description": "11308643 - Incorporated on 13 April 2018",
      "matches": {
        "snippet": [],
        "title": [
          1,
          3
        ]
      },
      "company_type": "ltd",
      "company_status": "active",
      "links": {
        "self": "/company/11308643"
      },
      "company_number": "11308643",
      "description_identifier": [
        "incorporated-on"
      ],
      "address": {
        "locality": "London",
        "postal_code": "WC1N 3AX",
        "premises": "27 ",
        "address_line_1": "Old Gloucester Street",
        "country": "United Kingdom"
      },
      "date_of_creation": "2018-04-13",
      "kind": "searchresults#company",
      "snippet": "",
      "address_snippet": "27  Old Gloucester Street, London, United Kingdom, WC1N 3AX"
    },
  ],
  "kind": "search#companies",
  "start_index": 0,
  "page_number": 1,
  "total_results": 184
}
```

Logged in console

[image: console]

Comment: Your description of the problem is unclear. A sample of the actual JSON data you're attempting to iterate would be much better than a PHP `print_r()` dump

Comment: If I had to guess, you're iterating over all the key / value pairs in the entire object. What you want instead is to iterate over `data.items` only, ie `data.items.forEach(({ title, company_number }) => console.log(title, company_number))`

Comment: @Phil Sorry buddy, late night! I've updated it with the JSON data - how would I go about looping through the items? This is just one, I'm loading about 50 results you see in the full result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Issue:**

The behavior you're seeing is because you're iterating over all of the properties on your returned data, and then trying to iterate of the 'items' property of each one. This results in you getting one successful return and then 16 (or however many properties the json has) undefined returns.

**The Solution:**

Instead of using nested $.each loops, you can refactor this block:

```
success: function(data){
          $.each(data, function(){
              $.each(this, function(key, val) {
                  console.log(val.title + " : company number : " + val.company_number);
                  $('[data-select]').append(`
                      <option value='`+key+`'>`+val.title+`</option>
                  `);
              });
          });
      },
```

... to a much simpler version:

```
success: function(data){
            $.each(data.items, function(key, val) {
                console.log(val.title + " : company number : " + val.company_number);
                $('[data-select]').append(`
                    <option value='`+key+`'>`+val.title+`</option>
                `);
              });
      },
```

In the block above, I got rid of your outer $.each loop and instead changed your inner loop to target 'data.items'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ryan, you're amazing! I never even thought to change that. Thanks buddy!